# How to use SOAP service generated class methods?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I have created a SOAP service.

Now i want to consume it in a c# client application. I added the service using '`Add service reference`' and service reference is added to client.

All my service entities are in service. And in current scenerio i can't move them to a common library.

Problem is, my service endpoint is accepting `List<Foo>` as parameter.

`Foo` has a method `Boo`.

In client, when i try to `Foo.Boo()` i get `Cannot resolve symbol Boo` error.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately only methods on the service itself are exposed via a SOAP web service, methods on objects used as parameters or return values are not.  If the method relates to a server-side operation then you could expose it at the service root level taking the instance object as parameter, or if it relates to a client-side operation you could consider adding it as a client-side extension method.